# Joomla Custom Content Not Saving

Tags: joomla

I have written a simple plugin to include custom content against Joomla articles. Here's the code:

```
defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ( 'Restricted access' );

class plgContentHomegrid extends JPlugin {

    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {

        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = $app->input->get('option');

        switch($option) {

            case 'com_content':
                if ($app->isAdmin()) {

                    JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');

                        $form->loadFile('homegrid', false);

                }

                return true;

        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

This works fine, the additional fields are displayed as a separate tab in admin, data saves correctly and everything's perfect. So far so good...however, I only want to display the additional tab on the home page. So, I amended the code so the additional form is only displayed for the home page:

```
 if( $data->featured == 1 ){

    $form->loadFile('homegrid', false);

}
```

The form now only displays on the home page admin screen as needed BUT the data is not saved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try asking on [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem comes because my conditional references the $data item, which is not populated during save, just display (as recorded [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/custom-content-plugin-not-saving-data-when-conditionally-restricted-to-single-pa/9262#9262))

So, a little investigation finds this solution works fine:

```
if( $data->featured == 1 || $_POST['jform']['featured'] == 1 ){

    $form->loadFile('homegrid', false);

}
```

There seems to be no documentation anywhere on this!!